# If $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $c$, is $f'(x)$ continuous at $x=c$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm pretty sure the statement

"If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, is $f'(x)$ continuous at $x=c$"

is wrong and there are quite a lot of counterexamples to that, but what if we add a " differentiable on neighbourhood" condition?

Or, could the hypothesis be strengthened to:

"If $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $c$, is $f'(x)$ continuous at a neighbourhood of $c$?"

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Take $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $0$ at $x=0$. This function is differentiable in a neighborhood of zero (in particular $f'(0)=0$) but $f'$ is discontinuous at zero since $\lim_{x\to} f'(x)$ does not exist. Derivatives cannot have jump discontinuities, but they can have essential discontinuities, like in the example.